# Launch new activity after successful Facebook login, Facebook Api v.4.0 | Android

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, facebook-login

I'm an android noob and want to use Facebook Api to login to my app. I have managed to setup Facebook login using LoginButton class on a fragment from Facebook documentation. Now I can login using Facebook, each time I succesfully login I get the logout button but I need to be able to redirect to another activity after successful login or when logged in. How can I track login status and redirect since in Api 4.0 Session doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Activity or Fragment implements `FacebookCallback` (my exampel here uses a Fragment, but its easy to adapt.) Make sure you have the following member variables:

```
CallbackManager mFacebookCallbackManager;
LoginButton mfbLoginButton;
```

Then setup those variables in your onCreate:

```
    mFacebookCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    mfbLoginButton = (LoginButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.facebook_login_button);
    mfbLoginButton.setFragment(this);
    mfbLoginButton.registerCallback(mFacebookCallbackManager, this);
```

Ensure you add this to enable the callback:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mFacebookCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

The FacebookCallback will then give you this method:

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(Object o) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Facebook onSuccess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

You can start your new activity from onSuccess. Good luck.