# login to app using facebook not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I've started an app which has Facebook login. So I integrated facebook sdk and done the following things.

Activity.java

```
public class StartActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private CallbackManager callbackManager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = this.getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, new LoginFragment())
                .commit();
    }

}
}
```

LoginFragment.java

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
private EditText et_userName, et_passWord;
private Button btn_login, btn_register, btn_fb;
private LoginButton loginButton;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
View rootView;
Context mContext;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment, container, false);
    et_userName = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.userName);
    et_passWord = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.passWord);
    btn_login = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    btn_register = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.registerButton);
    loginButton = (LoginButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    btn_login.setOnClickListener(this);
    btn_register.setOnClickListener(this);
    mContext = getActivity();
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "User ID: " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId() + "\n" + "Auth Token: "
                    + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Attempt Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Attempt Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.loginButton:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "LOGIN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.registerButton:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "REGISTER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}
```

}

when I click the LoginButton, Facebook login page is opened and ask for authorization, but after I press ok nothing happens just go back to fragment page.
This exact thing worked(userId and AccessToken as Toast and changing loginbutton to Logout) when I used an Activity. I used same logic in the fragment.
What went wrong??Help

Comment: What is your problem actually?

Comment: Cannot login using facebook

Comment: Then you should change question title and some description. becoz both are opposite.

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30643545/launch-new-activity-after-successful-facebook-login-facebook-api-v-4-0-androi

Answer (score 2):

In your `Activity` that contains the `Fragment`, do this

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {    
    fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

If you don't have a reference to your `Fragment`, you can get it using

```
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(<container-res-id>);
```